# Error messages not translated in observer

Tags: localisation, ce-1.9.2.2

I have placed the error messages like below in my observer.php

```
$msg = Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('You had already added the subscription in previous session.Add the subscription again and proceed to checkout');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($msg);
```

and added the translation in

```
app/locale/es_ES/Mymodule.csv
```

But the still the messages are not translated. 
Can anyone suggest a workaround ?

Comment: Have you defined Mymodule.csv in module's config.xml ?

Comment: Can you post your config.xml file?

Comment: have you fixed this?